# WPA2 audit tool

Tags: passwords, brute-force, wpa2

For the purposes of my own research, I have a very modest budget to set up a modest WPA2 brute-forcer supported by GPU(s).

I've done some homework:

- [Brute-Force GPU Password Crackers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36374/brute-force-gpu-password-crackers)
- [How to setup GPU for Cracking WPA/WPA2?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26358/how-to-setup-gpu-for-cracking-wpa-wpa2)
- [oclHascat? No.](http://hashcat.net/forum/thread-2317.html)

But I am still left with some questions on how to proceed.

- Is Pyrit a good WPA2 auditor tool? The current Backtrack 5 R3 distribution has it installed by default, which suggests so, however, the last [activity](https://code.google.com/p/pyrit/downloads/list) was in 2011. If not, what alternatives do you suggest?
- If not, what other tool(s) should I investigate?
- Does anyone have any examples of some successful configurations that worked for this, and without a lot of headaches?

The question is not intended to invite argument or open-ended discussion. I am looking for some field-tested solutions that actually work, before investing into the hardware.

Comment: Check out Kali Linux.

Comment: [Meta discussion about the closure of this question](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/1271/vote-to-close-why-doesnt-this-question-follow-the-faq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyrit is probably a good WPA2 audit tool, though I've yet to try it.
Relying on a few tools that make specific assumptions about hardware, and buying fast, expensive hardware like GPUs  may not be the best solution. If planning a dictionary attack, the disk I/O over gigabytes of data may be the bottleneck.